# How do I get the nth row in a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would you get the nth row (i.e 5th row) from the result of a query in SQL Server?

Comment: You want a sql query that returns the values in the column defined as the fifth comlumn in that table?  Such that if one were to insert another column as the 2nd column, push the subsequent columns down, then this query we're discussing would then return what had previously been the 4th column?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Are you looking for the fifth row, or the fifth column?

Comment: Since the title of the question is "How do I get the nth row in a SQL Server table" I think it's pretty clear he wants the fifth row, not the fifth column.

Comment: And then the text of the question asks for the 5th value from a row.  Hence the confusion.  Is the title wrong or the question text wrong?  You guess is as good as mine certainly.

Comment: Good point.  He should clarify.

Comment: Hi All, i m in same situation but working for MSSQLServer where Order by clause not works in inner query then what will the solution..?

Comment: I understood the question and it has 16 up votes so far. Clearly lots of people understood it.  It seems like a real question to me and it shouldn't have been closed.

Comment: You can do it by using offset and fetch. But adding answers seems to be disabled.

Answer (score 28):

SQL Server 2005 and newer:

```
with Records AS(select row_number() over(order by datecreated) as 'row', * 
                from Table)
select * from records
where row=5
```

You can change the order by to determine how you sort the data to get the fifth row.

Tested on my local install: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4053.00 (X64)   May 26 2009 14:13:01   Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7600: )

Comment: Works great, but only for SQL 2008.

Comment: No works fine on SQL 2005 which is what I am running

Comment: My mistake, 2005 and up do support this.  Thanks Josh!

Answer (score 13):

As of 2005, the ROW_NUMBER() function is available.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
   SELECT r.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeField ASC) AS RowNum
) sorty
WHERE RowNum = 5
```

Answer (score 12):

You have many choices, based on [this link](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-get-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-server-table.html).  All these techniques apply to SQL 2000.  The one I've used before is option #1, where you take a 5-element subset ordered one way and then pick the "TOP" row out of the subset ordered the other way.  Works great!

```
SELECT TOP 1 FName 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT TOP 5 FName 
    FROM Names 
    ORDER BY FName 
) sub 
ORDER BY FName DESC
```

In SQL 2005 and up it's easier -- you have row ordering functions such as [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) which will do what you need directly.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() is present in SQL Server 2005...

Comment: Take note that when using this method and there are n < 5 rows, then you will get the nth row and not nothing. For example, if there are 4 rows in Names then this will return the 4th row. This can be good or bad depending on what you expect.

Answer (score 4):

---

You can make use of Common Table Expression (CTE) and Window Function, ROW_NUMBER() (compatability from SQL 2005) to solver your problem.

Let us assume that the table name is tableOne and it has three columns (col1, col2, col3)

To make the definition complete, you need to specify the order with respect to which you want the rows numbered. The following scripts should help you get the nth row of the table.

---

```
--table definition
create table tableOne
(
    col1 varchar(10)
    ,col2 varchar(10)
    ,col3 varchar(10)
)
go
-- sample data creation
insert into tableOne VALUES ('c11','c12','c13')
insert into tableOne VALUES ('c21','c22','c23')
insert into tableOne VALUES ('c31','c32','c33')
insert into tableOne VALUES ('c41','c42','c43')
insert into tableOne VALUES ('c51','c52','c53')
insert into tableOne VALUES ('c61','c62','c63')
go
-- obtaining nth row using CTE and Window Function
WITH NthRowCTE AS
(
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY col1) AS RNum
        , *
    FROM tableOne
)
SELECT * FROM NthRowCTE WHERE RNum = 5
GO
```

---

WITH CTE and Window Function, you have the complete flexibility to output data the way you want.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using SQL Serever 2005 or above you can use CTE functionality.

Otherwise you can use this simple query

```
SELECT TOP 1 EmpID  
FROM  (SELECT TOP 5 EmpID FROM EmpMaster ORDER BY Salary) T
ORDER BY Emp DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

A BIT more/different than you asked for, but here is some stuff:
Say you have a need to find the nth row of one table, on a specific datetime sequence and insert a value from it into another table if its unique identifier is not already in the other table.  This gets the value from that first tables nth row.
myuniquecol is an identifer/col that identifies the group of rows that all have the same value in the first table which have unique mydatetime values

```
( SELECT TOP 1 mycol FROM
    ( SELECT TOP 5 * FROM  mytable
        WHERE mytable.myuniquecol NOT IN (select myuniquecol from myothertable)
        AND mytable.myuniquecol = myuniquecol
        ORDER BY myuniquecol asc, mydatetime desc
    ) AS me
  ORDER BY myuniquecol desc, mydatetime asc
) AS mycolnew
```

This is useful to find the nth row in one table, and insert it in as the nth col in another table.

table1: myuniquecol, mycol, mydatetime

table2: myuniquecol, mycol1, mycol2, mycol3...

should work in any SQL :)

NOTE: mytable has a column called mycol

EDIT: took out some stuff because of SQL SERVER limitation on TOP

Comment: FYI, did it this way because the question was somewhat ambiguous.

Answer (score -1):

**SIMPLE**

**-- return first record**

select * from titles a where 1 = (select count(title_id) from titles b where a.title_id >= b.title_id)

**-- return second record and so on** 
select * from titles a where 2 = (select count(title_id) from titles b where a.title_id >= b.title_id)