# Finding nth row using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select top 20 * 
from dbo.DUTs D 
inner join dbo.Statuses S on d.StatusID = s.StatusID 
where s.Description = 'Active'
```

Above SQL Query returns the top 20 rows, how can I get a nth row from the result of the above query?  I looked at previous posts on finding the nth row and was not clear to use it for my purpose.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out the OFFSET keyword in SQL. It is used in paging of records, but may be of use to you here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the nth row in a SQL Server table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273558/how-do-i-get-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-server-table)

Answer (score 1):

The row order is arbitrary, so I would add an `ORDER BY` expression. Then, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (SELECT TOP 20 * FROM ... ORDER BY d.StatusID) AS d ORDER BY d.StatusID DESC
```

to get the 20th row.

You can also use [OFFSET](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618(v=sql.110).aspx) like:

```
SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY d.StatusID OFFSET 19 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

And a third option:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, rownum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY d.StatusID) FROM ...) AS a WHERE rownum = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use CTEs with the ROW_NUMBER() function to get my lists numbered in order. As @zambonee said, you'll need an ORDER BY clause either way or SQL can put them in a different order every time. It doesn't usually, but without ordering it yourself, you're not guaranteed to get the same thing twice. Here I'm assuming there's a [DateCreated] field (DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE()), which is usually a good idea so you know when that record was entered. This says "give me everything in that table and add a row number with the most recent record as #1":

```
; WITH AllDUTs
AS (
    SELECT  *
            , DateCreatedRank = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [DateCreated] DESC)
    FROM    dbo.DUTs D
            INNER JOIN dbo.Statuses S ON D.StatusID = S.StatusID
    WHERE   S.Description = 'Active'
    )
SELECT *
FROM AllDUTs
WHERE AllDUTs.DateCreatedRank = 20;
```

Comment: Thank you all for you prompt reply. I got it working. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM EMP ORDER BY ROWID DESC) WHERE ROWNUM<11
```

Answer (score 0):

It's another sample:

```
SELECT * ,CASE WHEN COUNT(0)OVER() =ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY number) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IsNth
FROM ( 
    select top 10 * 
    from  master.dbo.spt_values AS d
    where d.type='P'
) AS t
```

```
+------+--------+------+-----+------+--------+-------+
| name | number | type | low | high | status | IsNth |
+------+--------+------+-----+------+--------+-------+
| NULL | 0      | P    | 1   | 1    | 0      | 0     |
| NULL | 1      | P    | 1   | 2    | 0      | 0     |
| NULL | 2      | P    | 1   | 4    | 0      | 0     |
| NULL | 3      | P    | 1   | 8    | 0      | 0     |
| NULL | 4      | P    | 1   | 16   | 0      | 0     |
| NULL | 5      | P    | 1   | 32   | 0      | 0     |
| NULL | 6      | P    | 1   | 64   | 0      | 0     |
| NULL | 7      | P    | 1   | 128  | 0      | 0     |
| NULL | 8      | P    | 2   | 1    | 0      | 0     |
| NULL | 9      | P    | 2   | 2    | 0      | 1     |
+------+--------+------+-----+------+--------+-------+
```