# How to get avg of the second purchase?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in a DB where I keep userID, data purchase and price. I would like to get avg of the second purchase for all users. (avg of all second purchases)

I tried to solve my problem but I stuck. I get avg of all purchases but I don't know what should I do next.

```sql
SELECT AVG(purchase) FROM order;
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: how does your table look like? please provide more info

Comment: You need to do some more research. SO itself has many answers to similar questions [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2273558/how-do-i-get-the-nth-row-in-a-sql-server-table)

Comment: Note that order is a reserved word, and hence I'll-advised as a table/column identifier

Comment: @Strawberry right, actually my column has a different name, I've just used it here for better understand.

Comment: The rule applies to tables too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use window functions:

```
select avg(price)
from (select o.*, 
             row_number() over (partition by userId order by purchasedate) as seqnum
      from orders o
     ) o
where seqnum = 2;
```

Comment: I've tried 'over' before but there is a mistake, I use mySql, is there over allowed? Syntax Error: Unexpected '(' opening parenthesis.  I'm confused.

Comment: @Angelo . . . MySQL has supported window functions since version 8.